# WCF with basic authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I was referring to this link in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733775.aspx msdn  for basic authentication. The code specified is using basic authentication but no option is there for providing username and password. How can we change the specification in this link to accept user name and password.

Client is not giving any exception even without specifying any user name and password. So what is the impact of writing this setting

clientCredentialType="Basic"

If user do not provide any custom authentication.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915545/how-to-implement-webservicehost-authentication) can help. It configures it programmatically, not by conf files.

Comment: Are you having trouble setting the username and password on the client side or are you having trouble forcing your service to authenticate the client before processing the request?

Comment: I was just trying to explore if we set clientCredetial as Basic then where system tries to perform authentication. As in the code of msdn link there is a client credential is defined but no code is added to perform validation.