# WCF security failing

Tags: c#, wcf

I am self-hosting a WCF service.  This service should provide a custom authentication method that can be used to authenticate our customer applications that will connect to it.  I have written a custom username/password validator, but I don't think it's even being used.  When I attempt to call the service, I get the message "The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted."

App.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="basicHttpBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://win8drewdev:8001/TestService/MEX"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate findValue="0e 99 26 9b 04 20 93 86 5e 65 ad bb 7e 6d ea 62 8a 8a 07 7a" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber"/>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="SimpleTestValidator.WcfValidator, SimpleTestValidator"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="SimpleAuthBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="SimpleTestServer.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="basicHttpBehavior">
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://win8drewdev:8000/TestService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SimpleAuthBinding" contract="SimpleTestServer.ITestService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Per the answer below, I'm attaching a trace log of when the problem happens.  It would appear to indicate that something is happening on the client side, but I'm still not sure where that leaves me.

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
    <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
        <EventID>131075</EventID>
        <Type>3</Type>
        <SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
        <Level>2</Level>
        <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-09-11T12:13:38.0193252Z" />
        <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
        <Correlation ActivityID="{3c51d0c7-20ae-4401-b57b-771ebdbb8f83}" />
        <Execution ProcessName="SimpleTestServer.vshost" ProcessID="1572" ThreadID="18" />
        <Channel />
        <Computer>WIN8DREWDEV</Computer>
    </System>
    <ApplicationData>
        <TraceData>
            <DataItem>
                <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
                    <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
                    <Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
                    <AppDomain>SimpleTestServer.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
                    <Exception>
                        <ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
                        <Message>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:10:00'.</Message>
                        <StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.ReadAsyncResult.HandleIO(IConnection connection)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.IOAsyncResult.OnAsyncIOComplete(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.TracingConnectionState.ExecuteCallback()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.WaitCallback(Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.FinishRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsyncCompleted(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationAsyncFailure(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace>
                        <ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:10:00'. ---&amp;gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
                        <InnerException>
                            <ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
                            <Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message>
                            <StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)</StackTrace>
                            <ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)</ExceptionString>
                            <NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode>
                        </InnerException>
                    </Exception>
                </TraceRecord>
            </DataItem>
        </TraceData>
    </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

Here's the trace activity from the client:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
  <System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
    <EventID>131075</EventID>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-09-11T12:53:17.8882554Z" />
    <Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Correlation ActivityID="{b3316328-1b82-4aa3-b45c-ba8e7fd42c20}" />
    <Execution ProcessName="SimpleWcfClient.vshost" ProcessID="1816" ThreadID="9" />
    <Channel />
    <Computer>USSDEV08WS02</Computer>
  </System>
  <ApplicationData>
    <TraceData>
      <DataItem>
        <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
          <TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
          <Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
          <AppDomain>SimpleWcfClient.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
          <Exception>
            <ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
            <Message>A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.</Message>
            <StackTrace>
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SslStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp;amp; remoteSecurity)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUpgrade(Stream stream)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection&amp;amp; connection, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper&amp;amp; timeoutHelper)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper&amp;amp; timeoutHelper)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper&amp;amp; timeoutHelper)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
              at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
              at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.ExecuteMessage(Object target, IMethodCallMessage methodCall)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeChannel(IMethodCallMessage methodCall)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
              at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp;amp; msgData, Int32 type)
              at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
              at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp;amp; msgData, Int32 type)
              at SimpleWcfClient.TestService.ITestService.Hello()
              at SimpleWcfClient.Program.Main(String[] args)
              at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
              at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
              at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
              at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
              at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
              at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
            </StackTrace>
            <ExceptionString>
              System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---&amp;gt; System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---&amp;gt; System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted
              --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
              at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
              at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
              at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
              at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
              at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
              at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
              at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
              at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
              at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
              at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
              at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
              at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SslStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp;amp; remoteSecurity)
              --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
            </ExceptionString>
            <InnerException>
              <ExceptionType>System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
              <Message>A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.</Message>
              <StackTrace>
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
                at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
                at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SslStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp;amp; remoteSecurity)
              </StackTrace>
              <ExceptionString>
                System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception. ---&amp;gt; System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted
                --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
                at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
                at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
                at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SslStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp;amp; remoteSecurity)
              </ExceptionString>
              <InnerException>
                <ExceptionType>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
                <Message>The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted</Message>
                <StackTrace>
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SslStreamSecurityUpgradeInitiator.OnInitiateUpgrade(Stream stream, SecurityMessageProperty&amp;amp; remoteSecurity)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamSecurityUpgradeInitiatorBase.InitiateUpgrade(Stream stream)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.InitiateUpgrade(StreamUpgradeInitiator upgradeInitiator, IConnection&amp;amp; connection, ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IDefaultCommunicationTimeouts defaultTimeouts, TimeoutHelper&amp;amp; timeoutHelper)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper&amp;amp; timeoutHelper)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper&amp;amp; timeoutHelper)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
                  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
                  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.ExecuteMessage(Object target, IMethodCallMessage methodCall)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeChannel(IMethodCallMessage methodCall)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
                  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp;amp; msgData, Int32 type)
                  at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.ClientSecurityChannel`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
                  at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
                  at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp;amp; msgData, Int32 type)
                  at SimpleWcfClient.TestService.ITestService.Hello()
                  at SimpleWcfClient.Program.Main(String[] args)
                  at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
                  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
                  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
                  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
                  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
                  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
                  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
                  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
                </StackTrace>
                <ExceptionString>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted</ExceptionString>
                <NativeErrorCode>80090304</NativeErrorCode>
              </InnerException>
            </InnerException>
          </Exception>
        </TraceRecord>
      </DataItem>
    </TraceData>
  </ApplicationData>
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

For anyone who stumbles across this post, I've found the answer and it wasn't in any of the above.  I am creating my own certificates for use with this as it's a closed system, we don't want to purchase certificates for every machine involved and the locations of the machines prohibit using Windows Certificate Authority.  For some reason (that I'm still trying to fathom), when I request a certificate from one machine, sign it on another and then store it on the original machine it can't find the private key associated with the certificate.  I'm not sure exactly why that's happening, but that is what is causing this problem as WCF can't use the key to encrypt/decrypt data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915545/how-to-implement-webservicehost-authentication ?

Comment: I'm not really sure how anything at that link helps?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things that could be done.

First of all,

Try removing the spaces in the  `findValue="0e 99 26 9b 04 20 93 86 5e 65 ad bb 7e 6d ea 62 8a 8a 07 7a"`

Second,

Make the following changes in the **behaviour of the Client app.config** and install the service certificate in the **TrustedPeople** store of the client machine.

```
        <behavior name="ClientCertificateBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate x509FindType="FindByThumbprint"
                storeName="TrustedPeople"
                storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                findValue="9d4c41cde9d2b82d751a5416fd2eb6df98d3b7545"/>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode ="PeerOrChainTrust"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
```

Third,
Use **Custom binding** in the service config and app config

```
     <customBinding>
        <binding name="UserNameCertificate" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="01:00:00" maxPendingChannels="128" flowControlEnabled="true" />
          <binaryMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </binaryMessageEncoding>
          <security authenticationMode="SecureConversation" requireDerivedKeys ="true">
            <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="UserNameForCertificate" />
          </security>
          <tcpTransport maxPendingConnections="100" listenBacklog="100" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferPoolSize="1073741824" maxBufferSize="1073741824" maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
```

Finally,
If the problem still persists try switching off the **security to None** and check if it works. If it does, it could be a domain issue. 
(Don't forget to add the tcp port to firewall exceptions.)

Start WCF tracing which would give you more insight on the actual problem. Refer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271517/how-to-turn-on-wcf-tracing)

Comment: None of that changed anything.  Still getting "The Local Security Authority cannot be contacted."  Of course it does work with security turned off, but that still doesn't tell me why it won't work with security turned on and that's what I need.

Comment: Is it possible to debug the code and set a breakpoint in the custom validator? If it is not reached by authentication invocations, the setup is somehow buggy.

Comment: I've tried that and the custom validator is never called.  It's breaking during SSPI negotiation for some reason.

Comment: Did WCF tracing on the client side give you any details ?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this problem? I'm having the exact problem