# how to authenticate user with rest service-wcf WebHttpBindig?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, web

I have a server-client project written in c#. 
I want to change the client side to a web client so we can open it with the browser. So I decided to make a WCF rest service that will replace the server side. The binding that I am using for the service is webHttpBinding.
My problem is with the behavior of the service. The service data (vars etc..) is initialize after every call. If i add the `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]` 
it doesn't change anything. If I use `[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]`, it works but I guess that the service instance will be the same for every client.

I have a simple html web page that get a username and password from the client and post it to the service. The service check the Login info with the user database and response. My problem is that i can't save the user status as logged in or not because after every post/get method the service is reset.

what should I do?

Comment: You don't need a *Session*. You can implement ,for ex, *BasicAuthentication*. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915545/how-to-implement-webservicehost-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard issue you have to deal with when trying to maintain a session over HTTP, which is what webHttpBinding is using.  Even if you try to force it to have a session, it won't.  RESTful services don't work that way.

A high level overview of what you have to do is have the service create a token it gives the client upon initial authentication (probably to be stored in a cookie), which the client will then send back with each request.  The service can then use that token to check if the client is logged into a particular account with each request.  You probably want to make tokens expire after a certain duration (might be 1 month, 1 week, 1 day, 10 minutes, depending on your application).

You can find some more information here:

[RESTful Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication)

[SPA best practices for authentication and session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963273/spa-best-practices-for-authentication-and-session-management)

[Authentication, Authorization and Session Management in Traditional Web Apps and APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960131/authentication-authorization-and-session-management-in-traditional-web-apps-and)